# DrawListViewItemEventArgs.DrawDefault Property on ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'd like to implement owner draw for just one or two items in a ListView.

I found the `DrawListViewItemEventArgs.DrawDefault` property but am not clear on its use. The [MSDN example for this property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawlistviewitemeventargs.drawdefault.aspx) simply prints its value, which is completely useless for understanding how it's used.

Do I need to set this property is every call to `DrawItem()`, or is there a way to set this for those items I do not want to owner draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set it to true only if you want the normal listview item drawing to happen.  Which occurs after your DrawItem event handler returns.  And will over-draw anything you drew.

This is not typical, you usually implement the event to draw the item a different way.  Which makes the default value of false the normal usage, no further drawing occurs after your event handler completes.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. The flag is checked after `DrawItem()` returns, and the default drawing will take place at that time if this property is true. This allows arbitrarily complex control over which items should be drawn using the default drawing code.

Answer (score 1):

If my memory serves me correctly you need to do something like this:

```
private void ListView1_DrawItem(Object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e) {
  if (mycustomdraw) // Do we need to draw it or use the default drawing
  {
    e.DrawDefault = false; // This may be set to false by default
    // Draw the list item here
  }
  else
    e.DrawDefault = true; // Tell the listview to use the default drawing
}
```